# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

When I try to sync the project in Android Studio, it gives me the following error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/home/bunny/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2/gradle-3.2.pom
    file:/home/bunny/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2/gradle-3.2.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2/gradle-3.2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2/gradle-3.2.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

I have done many researches, looking thru SO answers, but still can't find a solution. The following are the `build.gradle`s in my project directory and my app directory:

[image]

Can anyone help me? Please!!! I need to work back on my project!!